# push forward of structure sheaf

Tags: algebraic-geometry

let $f:\Bbb{P}^r\times S \to S $ be projection morphism. Is it true that $f_\ast \mathcal{O}_\Bbb{P^r\times S}(n)=H^0( \Bbb{P}^r, \mathcal{O}_\Bbb{P^r}(n))\otimes \mathcal{O}_S$?

Comment: Everything is over a field $k$?

Comment: yes consider over $C$

Comment: Isn't the base change theorem useful here?

Comment: for this diagram?                   $\require{AMScd} \begin{CD} \Bbb{P^r}\times S @>>>   \Bbb{P^r} \\ @VVV @VVV\\ S  @>>> SpecC  \end{CD}$

Comment: You have a very very strange way of writing MathJax code. See my edit to this quesiton for proper usage.